# Firebase dosent support 4.0.4 devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Just a few days back, I integrated FireBase Android Analytics SDK into my app. I don't know why but, it tracks stats from only devices whose Android version is greater than 5.1.1. SDK says MinSDKLevel is 8, but is that the case for analytics too ?

Comment: Are the devices from which you are not seeing events your own test devices or user devices running a published app?  FWIW--I have been experimenting with Firebase Analytics on devices running 5.0.1 and 4.4.2.  I see events on the Firebase Analytics console from all of them.

Comment: My own, i can also see 4.4+ devices.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log output using [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log)?  This might provide some clues.

Comment: I didn't keep any extra log events, just the default Analytics, added core dependency in gradle scrpt, and created an instance in my main activity(just in case). Also i changed my 4.0.4 rom to cm (4.4.4) and it starts detection in "Monthly Active users". Tested with M(other phone), it works fine again. Not to mentions, Push Notifications works fine with all of them.